# Angular Material sorting not able to sort columns

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have implemented mat sort in two components using the same method. In one component is working fine but in other component it is not working due to some reason I am unable to find. I also checked the property should be same and in my code 2 of property out of all are according to the format but even those columns are not getting sorted.

Below is the code

HTML code

```
<!-- <section class="content-header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Patient Listing</h1>
  </div>
</section> -->

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
        <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="dateRangeFormGroup" [rangePicker]="picker" >
            <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date" [disabled]="true">
            <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date" [disabled]="true">
        </mat-date-range-input>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-date-range-picker #picker disabled="false">
            <mat-date-range-picker-actions>
                <button mat-button matDateRangePickerCancel>Cancel</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDateRangePickerApply (click)="onDateRangeApply()">Apply</button>
              </mat-date-range-picker-actions>
        </mat-date-range-picker>

        <mat-error *ngIf="dateRangeFormGroup.get('start').hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid start date
        </mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="dateRangeFormGroup.get('end').hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end date</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. Anything" #input>
  </mat-form-field>


<button class="float-right add-record-btn" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onRecordEdit()">Add
    Record</button>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="recordInformation" matSort *ngIf="recordInformation">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let record"> {{record.patientInformation.firstName | emptyString}} </td>
            <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let record"> {{record.patientInformation.lastName | emptyString}} </td>
            <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="treatment">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Treatment </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let record"> {{record.treatment | emptyString}} </td>
            <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> Total </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Amount </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let record"> {{record.amount}} </td>
            <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> {{getTotalAmount() | currency:'INR'}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="recordActions">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let record">
                <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Example icon-button with a menu">
                    <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="onRecordEdit(record)">
                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                        <span>Edit Record</span>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-menu-item (click)="onRecordDelete(record.id)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                        <span>Delete Record</span>
                    </button>
                </mat-menu>

            </td>
            <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr class="element-row" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        <tr class="total-footer-row" mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
            <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [pageSize]=25></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingService } from 'src/app/shared/loading.service';
import { PatientService } from '../patient.service';
import { RecordInformationModel } from 'src/app/models/records/RecordInformationModel';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { GuidModel } from 'src/app/models/common/GuidModel';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { EditRecordComponent } from './edit-record/edit-record.component';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from '../../shared/components/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { DateRangeModel } from 'src/app/models/records/DateRangeModel';
import { ToasterService } from '../../shared/toaster.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-record-list',
  templateUrl: './record-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./record-list.component.scss']
})
export class RecordListComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'treatment', 'amount', 'recordActions'];
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  recordInformation: MatTableDataSource<RecordInformationModel>;
  isAllInformation: boolean;
  dateRangeFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private loading: LoadingService,
    private patientService: PatientService,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toasterService: ToasterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
    this.loadNext();
  }

  initForm() {
    this.dateRangeFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      start: [new Date()],
      end: [new Date()]
    })
  }
  loadNext() {
    this.loading.show();
    this.isAllInformation = false;
    this.patientService.getAllRecords(this.getDateRangeValue()).subscribe(res => {
      this.recordInformation = new MatTableDataSource(res);
      this.recordInformation.sort = this.sort;
      this.recordInformation.paginator = this.paginator;
      
      this.isAllInformation = true
      this.loading.hide();
    }, error => {
      this.toasterService.error("Failed", error.error);
      this.loading.hide();
    })
  }

  onRecordEdit(recordInformation: RecordInformationModel = {
    id: new GuidModel().Empty,
    patientId: new GuidModel().Empty,
    recordDate: null,
    amount: null,
    treatment: null,
    patientInformation: null
  }) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditRecordComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      data: recordInformation
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.loadNext();
      }
    });
  }

  onRecordDelete(recordId: string) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
      data: { title: 'Delete Record?', message: 'Are you sure you want to permanently delete the record' }
    })

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.loading.show();
        this.patientService.deleteRecord(recordId).subscribe(() => {
          this.loadNext();
          this.toasterService.success("Success", "Record deleted Successfully");
          this.loading.hide();
        })
      }
    })
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.recordInformation.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    this.recordInformation.filterPredicate = (data, filter: string)  => {
      const accumulator = (currentTerm, key) => {
        return key === 'patientInformation' ? currentTerm + data.patientInformation.firstName + data.patientInformation.lastName : currentTerm + data[key];
      };
      const dataStr = Object.keys(data).reduce(accumulator, '').toLowerCase();
      // Transform the filter by converting it to lowercase and removing whitespace.
      const transformedFilter = filter.trim().toLowerCase();
      return dataStr.indexOf(transformedFilter) !== -1;
    };
  }

  onDateRangeApply() {
    this.loading.show();
    this.isAllInformation = false;
    this.patientService.getAllRecords(this.getDateRangeValue()).subscribe(res => {
      this.recordInformation = new MatTableDataSource(res);
      this.isAllInformation = true;
      this.recordInformation.sort = this.sort;
      this.recordInformation.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.loading.hide();
    }, error => {
      this.toasterService.error("Failed", error.error);
      this.loading.hide();
    })
  }

  getDateRangeValue() {
    let dateRangeFormGroupData = this.dateRangeFormGroup.value;
    let dateRange: DateRangeModel = {
      startDate: this.formatDate(dateRangeFormGroupData.start),
      endDate: this.formatDate(dateRangeFormGroupData.end)
    }
    return dateRange;
  }
  getTotalAmount() {
    let total = 0;
    this.recordInformation.data.forEach(record => {
      total = total + record.amount;
    })
    return total;
  }

  formatDate(date: Date) {
    if (date != null) {
      var offsetMs = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
      return new Date(date.getTime() - offsetMs);
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the console or log? Did you include `MatSortModule`?

Comment: @Eyeslandic Yes, I have included MatSortModule and there are no console errors.

Comment: I got it working. Found it somewhere on SO that if table is under ngif it does not work so used hidden instead. Also, name of cell and property should be same so need to use sortaccessor for complex object as of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Found it somewhere on SO that if table is under ngif it does not work so used hidden instead. Also, name of cell and property should be same so need to use sortaccessor for complex object as of mine